# Glassfish admin console's java.lang.RuntimeException

Tags: jdbc, connection-pooling, jdbc-odbc, ojdbc, glassfish-4.1

I have tried to create jdbc connection pool on my glassfish with the following properties(as seen on the image below). It connected succesfully makes me think it works right. However after I restarted the glassfish and tried to ping the pool, a RuntimeException appeared on my screen on a white screen. Not only when I ping it, but also when I click any tab and even the save and cancel button it end up to RuntimeException. I've tried every possible cause and search the net over and over but ended up this same exception. Please help. :(

RuntimeException steps to encounter

[image: Connection Pool Properties]

[image: RuntimeException]

```
    2015-04-29T15:19:29.144+0800|SEVERE: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException while attempting to process a 'beforeCreate' event for 'event132'.
    at com.sun.jsftemplating.layout.descriptors.LayoutElementBase.dispatchHandlers(LayoutElementBase.java:422)
    at com.sun.jsftemplating.layout.descriptors.LayoutElementBase.dispatchHandlers(LayoutElementBase.java:394)
    at com.sun.jsftemplating.layout.descriptors.LayoutComponent.beforeCreate(LayoutComponent.java:348)
    at com.sun.jsftemplating.layout.descriptors.LayoutComponent.getChild(LayoutComponent.java:288)
    at com.sun.jsftemplating.layout.LayoutViewHandler.buildUIComponentTree(LayoutViewHandler.java:556)
    at com.sun.jsftemplating.layout.LayoutViewHandler.buildUIComponentTree(LayoutViewHandler.java:551)
    at com.sun.jsftemplating.layout.LayoutViewHandler.buildUIComponentTree(LayoutViewHandler.java:507)
    at com.sun.jsftemplating.layout.LayoutViewHandler.buildUIComponentTree(LayoutViewHandler.java:507)
    at com.sun.jsftemplating.layout.LayoutViewHandler.createView(LayoutViewHandler.java:255)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.execute(RestoreViewPhase.java:205)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.doPhase(RestoreViewPhase.java:121)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:646)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:344)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at com.sun.webui.jsf.util.UploadFilter.doFilter(UploadFilter.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:316)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doChainInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:678)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:97)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:415)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:282)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:175)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:561)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:565)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at com.sun.jsftemplating.layout.descriptors.handler.Handler.invoke(Handler.java:442)
    at com.sun.jsftemplating.layout.descriptors.LayoutElementBase.dispatchHandlers(LayoutElementBase.java:420)
    ... 46 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: "segments" parameter is null.
    at org.glassfish.jersey.uri.internal.JerseyUriBuilder.appendPath(JerseyUriBuilder.java:711)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.uri.internal.JerseyUriBuilder.segment(JerseyUriBuilder.java:422)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.uri.internal.JerseyUriBuilder.segment(JerseyUriBuilder.java:71)
    at org.glassfish.admingui.common.util.RestUtil.appendEncodedSegment(RestUtil.java:531)
    at org.glassfish.admingui.common.handlers.RestApiHandlers.encodeUrl(RestApiHandlers.java:435)
    ... 52 more
```

Answer (score 10):

I faced this issue. I took two measures to fix it, not sure which one does the trick:

- Revert the JDBC driver to a version I was using in another glassfish installation;
- Clean the browser cache

After this I was able to edit the connection pool properties and ping the connection without the RuntimeException.

Hope it helps.

Comment: It was the second option. Thanks :)

Comment: Deleting the browser cookies fixes this.

Answer (score 3):

Clearing the browser cache resolved the issue for me.
(Literally spent hours trying to figure out this dumb thing).

Answer (score 1):

I know it is an old question but I've got the same behavior - even after adding the lates Jar-files.
My (as mostly) absolute trivial solution:

Just run Eclipse/Glasfish as Administrator. :-(

Answer (score 1):

Upgrade Glassfish from 4.1.1 to 4.1.2.

When I downloaded Java EE 7 SDK 7u2, it contained 4.1.1. In the same time Glassfish 4.1.2 is available in [Glassfish download](https://javaee.github.io/glassfish/download).